# How to avoid paying for interface virtual methods during inversion of control in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I work on this C++ code base which has a great architecture, very decoupled and easy to test. Though one thing that really bothers me is paying for virtual methods when most of times it isn't actually needed because the correct derived class is chosen once, during dependecy injection and dynamic polymorphism isn't needed. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


class IDog{
    public:
    virtual void bark() = 0;
    ~IDog() = default;
};


class Dog : public IDog {
    public:
    void bark() override {std::cout << "woof" << std::endl;}
};


void makeDogSound(std::unique_ptr<IDog> dog){
    dog->bark();
}

//prod main
int main(){
    makeDogSound(std::make_unique<Dog>());
}

//test

class MockDock : public IDog {
    public:
    void bark() override {std::cout << "mock woof" << std::endl;}
};

//test main
int main(){
    makeDogSound(std::make_unique<MockDock>());
}
```

I looked at some template based approachs like this one below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


class Dog{
    public:
    void bark()  {std::cout << "woof" << std::endl;}
};

template<typename DogT>
void makeDogSound(std::unique_ptr<DogT> dog){
    dog->bark();
}

//prod main
int main(){
    makeDogSound(std::make_unique<Dog>());
}

//test
class MockDock{
    public:
    void bark() {std::cout << "mock woof" << std::endl;}
};

//test main
int main(){
    makeDogSound(std::make_unique<MockDock>());
}
```

But it seems that:

- It would be difficult to keep track of the "dog interface" signature because they would be generated on the fly, every time I call a dog method inside makeDogSound.
- Autocomplete wouldn't work inside makeDogSound as it doesn't know about the Dog avaiable methods.

I don't rule out that maybe I'm not understanding well the template based approach.
It also seems to me that using C++20 concepts could be a way to ensure a strong interface at compile time.

Comment: Have you tried using the 'final' keyword?

Comment: If you 1) Add `final` to leaf classes. 2) turn up your compilers optimization level (`-O2` or `-O3`). 3) Enable the linkers optimization flag (yes, it has one). 4) Enable Link Time Optimization (LTO) in your build.  Then you'll often find that the compiler/linker can devirtualize function calls.

Comment: `makeDogSound(std::move(std::make_unique<Dog>()));` :( Please read your student book again, focus on move schematics chapters.

Comment: @MarekR Thanks for noticing. I was declaring as a variable before and decided to cut and paste the content inside the std::move instead of erasing it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik and Jesper thanks for this information. I wasn't aware about this optimization.

Comment: If your dependency injection occurs at compile time, you could use static polymorphism rather than `virtual` member function interface of dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: For any but the absolutely most performance-critical code paths the price one pays for virtual methods is not a consideration.    Not even remotely.    Is your dog going to be making a sound a thousand times a second?  OK, then it might matter.  Otherwise, it's not only premature optimization, it's permanently unnecessary optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that a C++20 concept would work well here to describe the interface:

```
template <typename Dog>
concept doglike = requires(Dog dog) {
    { dog.bark(); };
    { dog.name(); } -> std::convertible_to<std::string>; // example of how to specify return type, use std::same_as if you don't want conversions.
}
```

You could then write

```
template <doglike DogT>
void makeDogSound(std::unique_ptr<DogT> dog){
    dog->bark();
}
```

and if you try calling this function template with an object that isn't `doglike`, you'll get a clear compiler error telling you so.